# Manually Purging Nginx Cache Causes Errors in Log File

Tags: caching, nginx

I am attempting to clear the nginx cache when the CMS (ExpressionEngine) publishes new content.  I have been just purging the entire folder and letting the cache rebuild itself.  It seems to be working fine, but it is filling up the error logs with these entries:

```
2014/12/15 12:35:09 [crit] 21686#0: unlink() "/var/nginx/cache/default/6197dda0a6cadcec5563533cb6027580" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2014/12/15 12:35:10 [crit] 21686#0: unlink() "/var/nginx/cache/default/bb8eca6b51c655989bd717a9708b244e" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2014/12/15 12:35:10 [crit] 21686#0: unlink() "/var/nginx/cache/default/6f9b9aea38c5761a87cffd365e51e7a4" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

It seems that nginx keeps track of the cache files and gets confused when it goes to purge them after I already did.

Is there a better way to be purging the cache that doesn't cause these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, a way of doing this is specifying secret headers in nginx which will bypass cache, thus theoretically purging the existing files.

But also, there is nothing wrong in your way of doing it. The only ugliness is these logs, which invariably show up as `[crit]`, which they are not in case of manual purge. :)

Answer (score 0):

"It appears that these errors occur when NGINX itself tries to delete cache entries after the time specified by the inactive parameter of the fastcgi_cache_path directive. The default for this is only 10 minutes, but you can set it to whatever value you want. I’ve set it to 7 days myself, which seems to work well as I haven’t seen this error at all after changing it."

> Source: https://www.miklix.com/nginx/deleting-nginx-cache-puts-critical-unlink-errors-in-error-log/